# How to display mobile data usage for whole month and not last 7 days?

Tags: mobile-data, bandwidth

I have monthly cycle for measuring mobile data from 1st to 31st but it always measures last 7 days. How do I make it measure cycle I have configured?

[image: ![enter image description here]]

[Full resolution image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUnab.png)

Answer (score 0):

The vertical bars have handles where they meet the bottom of the graph, so you can adjust the date range that it presents. Just tap on the handle for the left bar and drag it all the way to the left of the graph to see your usage from the beginning if your billing cycle:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you, but every time these bars reset to range of 7 days and I have to adjust them again. I was wondering if I could set them for a range of whole month as default

Comment: @Boris_yo: You cannot. You'd have to find a custom ROM that implemented that feature, or perhaps an Xposed module or something. I'm not aware of anything that exists for that purpose. For whatever reason, the Android devs decided to make it show the last 7 days when the screen first appears, and that's not configurable.